# Best practice to read Firestore data that may be nil using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

None of the Firestore documentation offers TypeScript examples but TypeScript is a preferred language for Firebase Functions. But I don't know the language very well. In Swift, for example, Firestore snapshots can be `nil` and so too can field values, and accessing `nil` values directly can throw exception errors (crashes). I don't know if this is how TypeScript works with Firestore so what is the best practice for (1) accessing the snapshot itself and (2) dealing with fields that may or may not exist?

```
db.firestore().collection("userSettings").doc(recipientUserId).get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        const someField = snapshot.get("someField") || "defaultValueIfMissing"
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("ERROR", error)
})
```

Does this code adhere to best practices?

1. If the snapshot is either corrupt or empty (document doesn't exist), is this the proper way to access it, with a simple `if-else` statement?
2. If `someField` doesn't exist or does but has a `null` value, is this the proper way to give it a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the snapshot is either corrupt or empty (document doesn't exist), is this the proper way to access it, with a simple if-else statement?

The snapshot will not be corrupt.  It will either be entirely present or not.  The check for `snapshot.exists` is sufficient to know if the requested document was found.  It makes no claims about the contents of the document, as that could be anything.

> If someField doesn't exist or does but has a null value, is this the proper way to give it a default value?

Your code will give a default value to the named field in the following cases:

- The field does not exist
- The field value is null
- The field value is boolean false
- The field value is an empty string
- The field value is the number 0

TypeScript follows the same rules as JavaScript for determining the "[truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)" of a value.  You might want to read up on that in order to better understand how things work.

Fact of the matter is that what you're doing now might be OK, or it might not.  It depends on how *deeply* you want to check the field value to determine if it should take the default value.  If you want more specific conditions, you'll have to define those conditions, then implement them.  That's entirely up to you.

Comment: I understand. Then if we're expecting a boolean in one of the document's fields, would `const someBool = snapshot.get("someBool") || false` be a clean way to read it? It seems redundant to default to `false` if the value is already `false` (which is how you say TypeScript would handle this) but this at least gives us a default value if the field doesn't exist. Or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: How could it possibly be cleaner?  What you're describing is bare minimal code.